# Is it possible with to instrument @ngrx/store-devtools in lazy loaded module of the application and not in root module?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

Currently after trying to instrument @ngrx/store-devtools in lazy loaded module I get

> > Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DevtoolsExtension: (?).

Store is working correctly underneath.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the answer myself - it is NOT possible.